# Fill a column box selection with atlas_pagename in QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I am trying to dynamically fill a box with a column that has the same name as the atlas_pagename. I attempted to use `eval(atlas_pagename)` but was unsuccessful.

[image]

Does anyone have any tips or suggestions?

Results with `eval(atlas_pagename)`:

[image]

Comment: Does [%"atlas_pagename"%] work?

Comment: The variable is : `@atlas_pagename`

Comment: @Padmanabha, no.